# Task.ContinueWith not working how I expected

Tags: c#, task

Consider the following code. I am starting with a task that does nothing, and then using ContinueWith() to start 10 calls to a method that increments a counter.

When I run this program, it prints "0", indicating that the increment() method hasn't been called at all. I was expecting it to be called 10 times, since that's how many times I called ContinueWith().

If I uncomment the "Thread.Sleep(20)" line, then it prints "10" as expected.

This happens in either release or debug mode. My system is a core 2 quad with hyperthreading (8 logical cores) running Windows 7 x64.

I assume I have some kind of fundamental misunderstanding about how Task.ContinueWith() works....

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{}))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                {
                    task.ContinueWith(_=> increment());
                    // Thread.Sleep(20);  // Uncomment to print 10 instead of 0.
                }

                task.Wait();
            }

            // This prints 0 UNLESS you uncomment the sleep above.
            Console.WriteLine(counter); 
        }

        static void increment()
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
        }

        private static int counter;
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on what's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is simple: You wait on the task that is already finished. What you really want is to wait for the ten tasks you created in the loop:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    tasks.Add(task.ContinueWith(_=> increment()));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: Ah, so my mistake was thinking that the original task's Wait() method would wait for any ContinueWith() tasks that were appended to it!

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is to run a number of tasks sequentially. The real code is using the APM to read data asynchronously from a file, and I am then checksumming the blocks of data as they arrive, in a separate thread. 

I was just experimenting with using ContinueWith() to do this, but it seems like it would be a better idea to use a different approach.

In fact my previous effort simply added the blocks of data to a BlockingCollection<byte[]> which my checksumming thread accessed through the GetConsumingEnumerable() method. I now think that is the best approach.

Comment: @Matthew: Well, running them sequentially can be achieved by Jon's solution. But your previous approach sounds just fine. That's the way I would have implemented it.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. You're printing out the value when the *initial* task has completed - you're not waiting for the continuation to occur. In other words, when the initial task completes, 11 things happen:

- 10 new tasks start executing, each incrementing the counter
- You print out the counter

You could effectively chain all these together if you want:

```
task = task.ContinueWith(_=> increment());
```

Then when the original task finishes, one incrementer will fire. When *that* finishes, the next incrementer will fire. When that finishes [...]. And when the final incrementer has finished, your `Wait` call will return.

Comment: Your code will execute the tasks serially. Does his - and mine - execute the ten tasks in parallel?

Comment: @Daniel: Potentially. It depends what the default scheduler is, I suspect... and even if the scheduler is for the threadpool, these will occur sufficiently quickly that I would expect the tasks to complete before the half second required before a new thread is created. Isn't threading fun? :)

Comment: I know that it shouldn't make any difference in this scenario, but for me it wasn't clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the main body as follows:

```
        using (var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { }))
        {
            var t = task;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
               t = t.ContinueWith(_ => increment());
                // Thread.Sleep(20);  // Uncomment to print 10 instead of 0.
            }

            t.Wait();
        }
```

You will get `10` without sleeping. The main change is `t = t.ContinueWith(...)` and `t` is necessary because you're not allowed to change the `using()` variable.

Comment: I guess I was also creating a bunch of tasks and not disposing them (something which I could probably ignore anyway...)