# Task.WaitAll doesn't wait for child task?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Hello I have `_noOfThreads` as defined tasks to run at a time. So I keep continuing the Tasks by using `%` operator and at the end of the loop I have `Tasks.WaitAll`. This is the code snippet.

```
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
{

                if (index < _noOfThreads)
                    tasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(somedelegate);
                else
                    tasks[index % _noOfThreads].ContinueWith(task => { foo.bar(); }, 
                            TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
 }
  Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

However, I notice it doesn't wait for child tasks to complete. As soon as the parent tasks complete, the next line after `Task.WaitAll` gets executed. How do I change this code to wait for child tasks also?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Task.ContinueWith not working how I expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997480/task-continuewith-not-working-how-i-expected)

Comment: On a side note, what you appear to doing here is deciding task scheduling.  If you want to customize scheduling, you can look at deriving from [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx).  That said, the default scheduler already does a pretty good job of not overloading the system with threads when a large number of tasks are queued.

Comment: @Dan: That is not my concern. I don't know want to give this to TaskScheduler. I have a variable and I want to starts Tasks as many as that variable only. In short I want to simulate something like Semaphore where you define the number of threads and only that number of threads can enter that piece of code at a certain time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are allocating your Tasks as:

```
Tasks[] tasks = new Task[ _noOfThreads];
```

Change your code to be:

```
Tasks[] tasks = new Task[count];

for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
{

    if (index < _noOfThreads)
         tasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(somedelegate);
    else
         tasks[index] = tasks[index % _noOfThreads].ContinueWith(task => { foo.bar(); }, 
                            TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Give it a try! Good Luck :)

Answer (score 3):

You are waiting only for the original task.  To wait for all the continuations to complete, you need to call `WaitAll` on the continuation tasks.  Simple way to accomplish this would be to reassign each continuation task back to the original variable so you are waiting only on the final continuations:

```
else
    tasks[index % _noOfThreads] =
        tasks[index % _noOfThreads].ContinueWith(task => { foo.bar(); }, 
                        TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
```

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997480/task-continuewith-not-working-how-i-expected).